# Understanding an Induced Product on $\pi(G)$ Distinct from the Usual Product on $\pi(G)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

**Hypothesis:** Let $G$ be a topological group.  Let $\mu$ denote the group multiplication mapping on $G \times G$ to $G$ that is stipulated to be continuous.  Let $\pi_1(G,e) = \pi(G)$ denote the fundamental group of $G$.

**Question:** I've read elsewhere that there is a product $*$ induced by

$$
* : \pi(G) \times \pi(G) \cong \pi(G \times G) \overset{\pi(\mu)}{\rightarrow} \pi(G)
$$

I am confused by what exactly is meant here.  This product is distinct from the usual group product $\circ$ on $\pi(G)$.  If anything, what is meant by $\pi(\mu)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\mu\colon G\times G\to G$ is a continuous map. The map $\pi(\mu)\colon \pi(G)\times \pi(G)\to \pi(G)$ is the induced group homomorphism on fundamental groups.

As an example, if $G=S^1$ with complex multiplication as the group operation $\mu\colon S^1\times S^1\to S^1$, then $\pi(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi(S^1\times S^1)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. The induced map $\pi(\mu)\colon \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ maps $(u,v)$ to $u+v$.